# new line \n not registered when generating docx with js

Tags: javascript, newline, docx

I have javascript code to generate a docx document. This js code creates a `Paragraph`. With `TextRun()` I am adding text inside this paragraph:

```
 new docx.Paragraph({
    style: "text",
    children: [
        new docx.TextRun({
            text: 'line 1\n',
        }),
        new docx.TextRun({
            text: 'line 2\n',
        }),
        new docx.TextRun({
            text: 'line 3',
        })
    ]
})
```

`\n` gets ignored and all `TextRun()` are in the same line. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: It could be that you need the carriage return line too, `\r`?

Comment: I did this aswell. Nice hint, but it doesnt fix my issue

Comment: Try using "break" instead? https://docx.js.org/#/usage/text?id=break

Comment: Can I set the position (e.g. after my `text:` element) for the break?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `break:` element works fine, e.g.:

```
new docx.Paragraph({
    style: "text",
    children: [
        new docx.TextRun({
            text: 'line 1',
            break: 1
        })
    ]
})
```

If the `text:` String is much longer, with more characters I can add a new TextRun() with an empty text as workaround:

```
new docx.Paragraph({
    style: "text",
    children: [
        new docx.TextRun({
            text: 'This text is so long that the break is not at the end of the line'
        }),
        new docx.TextRun({
            text: '',
            break: 1
        })
    ]
})
```